# Extract fields with destructuring assignment syntax to a specific variable name

Tags: javascript, object, react-hooks, destructuring, spread-syntax

I am trying to extract specific fields from a returned object, specifically I want to separate the first field from then other three, but somehow I seem to only be able to do it keeping the original returned name of the returned element:

```
return {
   function1,
   string1,
   string2,
   function2  }
```

I try to extract the returned values as follows:

```
  const {function1, ...rest} = useField('firstField')
```

My problem is that I am using useField (a custom hook) three times for three different fields of a form, so I need three different names for three different "function1" returns:

```
const {function1, ...rest} = useField('firstField')
const {function1, ...rest} = useField('secondField')
const {function1, ...rest} = useField('thirdField')
```

I know I could solve this adding extra steps (declaring new constants), but I am trying to do it in an elegant, simple way. If I try to assign custom variable names to each function, it does not work, for instance:

```
const {firstFunction, ...rest} = useField('firstField')
const {secondFunction, ...rest} = useField('firstField')
const {thirdFunction, ...rest} = useField('firstField')
```

It seems to works returning an array instead of an object and it works, but as arrays assign each element a number (0: function1, 1: value1...) instead of field names (function1: function1, value1: value1...) it is not a good solution for my purposes.

Any idea of how to elegantly solve this issue? (I don't mind if the solution is in modifying the return or the spread destructuring).

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

With [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you can assign a destructured property to a new variable name using [`const { prop: name } = obj;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names), which is equivalent to `const name = obj.prop;` The left-hand side of the colon is the property name, and the right-hand side is the variable name. With that in mind, you can write the following in order to assign the `function1` property to three differently named variables:

```js
const {function1: firstFunction, ...rest} = useField('firstField')
const {function1: secondFunction, ...rest} = useField('secondField')
const {function1: thirdFunction, ...rest} = useField('thirdField')
```

Comment: Thank you!! That works perfectly. I had actually tried to do something similar with = instead of : (facepalm). I am a bit confused about the left and right hand sides though, as I am so used to have the right hand side be the value, would have never thought of using it as a variable assignment. Thank you again =)

Comment: @HigoChumbo `=` is to provide a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2) for the destructured property when the property is missing or explicitly set to the value `undefined`.